# There is a strange issue with session on the production servers

Tags: php, session, load-balancing

I built a few pages in hard coded PHP, on my environment everything is working properly,
but when i am deploying this pages to the production servers there is few problems
when the user is getting to one of my page sometimes he will be redirected to the home page,
and sometimes he will redirected to my page without any problem.

This is happening when the user do not have the session with the appropriate values.
there are two servers with load balancing between them, i deployed to both of them but still
this issue remains.

Thx in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty vague question. Since they're load balanced, it sounds simply like the session data is not shared between them?!??!!?!1one

Comment: We're not mind readers. Can you post some code?

Comment: this i a sample of my code
if(empty($_SESSION["userId"])){
  header("Location: ".USER_HOME_PAGE);
  exit;
 }
        
sometimes the user just redirected to USER_HOME_PAGE even if he had already the session data, i think deceze you right that the session is not shared between the servers, there is a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: Unless your two load-balanced servers are sharing session data, or you have your load balancer set to recognize sessions and maintain a session on just one system, chances are the user isn't always getting their session information loaded.

Comment: what i need to do so the two servers will have the shared session?
do i need to config the servers for that too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While you have multiple server for load balancing, you need to save session in database rather than saving physically.

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html

Above link will guide you how you can save session in DB.